# Manipulating the height of a div class in an HTML table using CSS and a wicket

Tags: javascript, css, wicket, html-table, html

I have the following CSS code:

```
.Divider {

padding-top:0px;
padding-bottom:500px;
}
```

and the following HTML

```
<tr>
<td align="left">
<a wicket:id="button">      
    <img wicket:id="buttonImg" align="center" style="width:70%"/>
</a>
</td>
<td align="left" >
<div class="Divider"/>
</td>
</tr>
```

I would have expected 500px to be added as padding at the bottom of the image. Instead it adds it top and bottom. I've tried fiddling with height - same result. Obviously I'm a stupid newbie but can anone give me a clue what form my stupidity is taking pls. Would be most grateful

Answer (score 0):

Try closing the Divider div this way.

```
<div class="Divider"></div>
```

Original Code Example **<div class="Divider" />** http://jsfiddle.net/rrBXU/1/
Example with **<div class="Divider"></div>** http://jsfiddle.net/rrBXU/2/

Answer (score 0):

You should be applying the padding to the same cell that the image is in.

You can do it with the `<div>` or apply the `padding-bottom` property to the `<img>`.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td align="left">
      <a wicket:id="button">
        <img id="buttonImg" align="center" style="width:70%"></a>
        <div class="Divider"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Also, if you give the containing table a class you'll have greater control over all elements within it by using CSS. Example:

```
<table class="container">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a><img src="..."></a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

.container { }
.container td { }
.container td img { }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put the img tag in a div and give it the same style.Or to make it easier just add a new div with the "Divider" class and put the image in it.
The code will be like this:

```
<td>
  <div class="Divider">
    ..image or other content..
  </div>
</td>
```

If there are other styling attributes in Divider:

```
<td>
  <div class="Divider2" style="padding-top:0px;padding-bottom:500px;">
    ..image or other content..
  </div>
</td>
```

Comment: `vspace` was depreciated in HTML4. Let's stay clear of that and promote current standards.